# How to retrieve/import object using MEF in Prism

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, prism, mef, prism-5

I have a requirement to have one object (`RuleFile`), representing file to be serialized, across the whole application like word (*.docs) file that will be associated with my application.

I am using Prism 5 along with MEF as a dependency injection container.

```
[Export]
[Serializable()]
public class RuleFile : NotificationBase, IRuleFile { }
```

Now i have decorated the object with `[Export]` and trying to import it in one of the `MyViewModel` but it is giving `null`.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [Import]
    private RuleFile RuleFile; // 'null' coming here
}
```

Kindly direct me what am i missing? Or tell me any other way to best handle this scenario.

Comment: Do you get any error? Is it because your member is private? On https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Declaring%20Imports it says "Note: note that importing or exporting private members (fields, properties and methods) while supported in full trust is likely to be problematic on medium/partial trust."

Comment: No error is coming. Even i changed my private member to public property as you mentioned but still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Prism so well. Are you configuring the MEF composition (container and catalogs) or is Prism supposed to take care of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking the value in the constructor? Imports that are decorated directly on the property are resolved after the constructor. If you want to access the `RuleFile` in the constructor you'd need to set it up like this

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RuleFile RuleFile { get; set; }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyViewModel(RuleFile ruleFile)
    {
        RuleFile = ruleFile;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the `IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification` which will give you a notification method to signify that the imports have been resolved. Like this

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import]
    public RuleFile RuleFile { get; set; }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        // Signifies that Imports have been resolved  
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out the same workaround myself but that doesn't answer my question because i was trying to use the RuleFile object after constructor was invoked. So it should not return null. However i am marking your answer as accepted until i get the real reason.

Comment: In that case, the only other thing I can think of is are you definitely using MEF to make the MyViewModel? I can't see an [Export] on it there but I don't know if you missed it for the example. Where is the code that creates the MyViewModel?